# Getting dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_NSJSONSerialization on IOS4

Tags: iphone, ios4

I get the following error when testing on iOS4:

> dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_NSJSONSerialization

While on iOS5 it's working fine.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: NSJSONSerialization class is new on iOS 5. On iOS 4, you need a third party library like http://stig.github.com/json-framework/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) README :

> "AFNetworking uses NSJSONSerialization if it is available. If your app targets a platform where this class is not available you can include one of the following JSON libraries to your project for AFNetworking to automatically detect and use."

With that being said, to prevent the following error make sure of two things

1. that JSONKit / SBJson / YAJL are included
2. That your "Deployment Target" is lower than iOS5 , that way `AFNetworking` would realize it can't use `NSJSONSerialization` and will fall back to one of the included JSON parsing classes.

Shai.

Answer (score 3):

@hoshi is right.  You can't use NSJSONSerialization on devices running older than iOS 5.0.

[Here's the documentation from Apple's site](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html).  For my own code I also use the SBJson library.

Comment: But i'm not using it (well not that i'm aware off).
I'm using JSONKit class.

Comment: do a search through your code and let me know if you see any NSJSONSerialization instances.

Comment: I've done the search and there's no result regarding NSJSONSerialization instances.

Comment: something in your code is asking for NSJSONSerialization ... could it be one of the other libraries you are including?  If you can't solve this, you're ultimately going to have to only allow your app to run on iOS 5.0 and newer (which hopefully won't be a big problem for your employer).

Comment: I also think that one  of the Frameworks I'm using is asking for that class.
Unfortunately, I must support IOS 4.0 devices, which means that i'll have to dig into this and find where NSJSONSerialization been used.

Thank you for your help anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be that the `AFNetworking` class is the one that use `NSJSONSerialization`.